# Newbie to React.js cannot determine proper Typescript Interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm [trying this react example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html), which I've put into the Visual Studio Code IDE. I've named this file below as table.tsx.  The example from react does not contain any of the interface definitions I've put in below.

[image]

I had to add the  generics (via the interface defs) to React.Component class declaration. The React.Component now requires this.  That part seemed to work.  Now I'm having trouble with the rest of the parameters as shown below...

There's a red line under colSpan because it doesn't like the string parameter?  The other red lines are most likely an issue because I haven't set up the props interface correctly?

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple issues here. As you mentioned, `colSpan` is expected to be a number, not a string, so it needs to look like this:

```
<th colSpan={2}>
```

You've also declared `props.product` to be an array, so `this.props.category` doesn't really make a lot of sense. What you probably want is something like `this.props[0].category`, but more likely you want to pass the category itself to the `ProductCategoryRow` component:

```
class ProductCategoryRow extends React.Component<{category:string},any>
```

You generally don't want to pass the same props shape to all your components. Your `ProductCategoryRow` should have different props than your `ProductRow`.